# Error al acceder a un servicio windows jboss en aplicación silverlight

Tags: silverlight

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en silverlight, la aplicación hace referencia a un servicio windows que esta en jboss,se agrega la referencia correctamente al proyecto, pero al correr la aplicación da el siguiente error:

No se pudo encontrar una directiva entre dominios en 'url de servicio': es posible que la aplicación de Silverlight no pueda obtener acceso a los servicios Web en tiempo de ejecución. Para obtener más información, póngase en contacto con el administrador del servidor web o presione F1 tras seleccionar esta advertencia

Probé el servicio con SOAP UI y funciona correctamente.
¿Que puedo hacer para que pueda acceder al servicio windows?

Agradecería mucho sus respuestas.